# How do define my own element class for use with Set

Tags: java, set

I have the following code:

```
public class MyElement {
    String name;
    String type;

    MyElement(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<MyElement> set = new HashSet<MyElement>();
        set.add(new MyElement("foo", "bar"));
        set.add(new MyElement("foo", "bar"));
        set.add(new MyElement("foo", "bar"));
        System.out.println(set.size());
        System.out.println(set.contains(new MyElement("foo", "bar")));
    }
}
```

which when executed comes back with:

```
3

false
```

I would have expected the result to be 1 and true. Why are my elements not being recognised as being the same and how do I rectify this?
Thanks,
Wayne.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()` on MyElement per the general contract.  Absent that `Set.contains()` will use the default implementation which compares the memory address of the objects.  Since you're creating a new instance of MyElement in the contains call it comes back as false.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

My final code was:

public class MyElement {
 String name;
 String type;

 MyElement(String name, String type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
 }

 public boolean equals(Object object) {
  MyElement myElement = (MyElement) object;
  return this.name.equals(myElement.name) && this.type.equals(myElement.type);
 }

 public int hashCode() {
  return (name + type).hashCode();
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You should override an equals(MyElement me) function.  Equals returns a boolean

Otherwise, you are checking that two items are the same instance of an object, not that their internal content is the same.

```
MyElement(String name, String type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

public boolean Equals<MyElement>(MyElement me) {
    return this.name.equals(me.name) && this.type.equals(me.type);
}
```